The signal result becomes a straight line on the DAC
I am using your program and made some changes, but when I use it in the function
HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)value, 89, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R); HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim4);
the signal result on the oscilloscope is not continuous. What I mean is, when I use a very long array, the result does not match what I expected. To help you understand, I am attaching two photos comparing the result I want and the result from the program.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have a signal result like the one on the left, but I want it to be like the one on the right. After investigating, it turns out that the length value in HAL_DAC_Start_DMA was manually changed. If it can be done automatically, please give suggestions so I don't have to set it manually.
program to check:
uint16_t hold_samples = 50;
uint16_t firstHalf[64] =
{
2100, 2149, 2250, 2350, 2450, 2549, 2646, 2742, 2837, 2929, 3020, 3108, 3193, 3275, 3355,
3431, 3504, 3574, 3639, 3701, 3759, 3812, 3861, 3906, 3946, 3982, 4013, 4039, 4060, 4076,
4087, 4094, 4095, 4091, 4082, 4069, 4050, 4026, 3998, 3965, 3927, 3884, 3837, 3786, 3730,
3671, 3607, 3539, 3468, 3394, 3316, 3235, 3151, 3064, 2975, 2883, 2790, 2695, 2598, 2500,
2400, 2300, 2199, 2098

}; 
// Nilai pada bagian pertama
uint16_t secondHalf[71] =
{
1997, 1896, 1795, 1695, 1595, 1497,1305, 1212, 1120, 1031, 944, 860, 779, 701, 627,
556, 488, 424, 365, 309, 258, 211, 168, 130, 97, 69, 45, 26, 13,4, 0, 1, 8, 19, 35, 56, 82,
113, 149, 200, 283, 336, 394, 456, 521, 591, 664, 740, 820, 902, 987, 1075, 1166, 1258,
1353, 1449, 1546, 1645, 1745, 1845, 1947, 1965, 1990, 2010, 2022, 2047
}; // Nilai pada bagian kedua
uint16_t totalSize = (sizeof(firstHalf) / sizeof(uint16_t)) + hold_samples + (sizeof(secondHalf) / sizeof(uint16_t));
    uint16_t index = 0;
    uint16_t n_firstHalf = (sizeof(firstHalf) / sizeof(uint16_t));
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n_firstHalf; i++) {
        value[index] = firstHalf[i];
        index++;
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < hold_samples; i++) {
        value[index] = 2048;
        index++;
    }
 
    int n_secondHalf = (sizeof(secondHalf) / sizeof(uint16_t));
    for (int i = 0; i < n_secondHalf; i++) {
        value[index] = secondHalf[i];
        index++;
    }
 
HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)value, 89, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim4);


I have a signal result like the one on the first pitcure, but I want it to be like the one on the right. After investigating, it turns out that the length value in HAL_DAC_Start_DMA was manually changed. If it can be done automatically, please give suggestions so I don't have to set it manually.

The signal that you produce is 100% exactly what you're trying to achieve (notice different scales in the pictures). It's just one period of it. If you repeat it, you will get the wave you want.

You have been asked to provide a MCVE for recent questions. Will you continue to refuse doing so? Also you did not really provide feedback for previous questions. That is not how StackOverflow works.

Whatever you put in your array, your signal will not be contiguous unless you tell your DMA to start again after the last value was transfered. You will need to wait (using an interrupt handler or using polling) until the DMA is completed and then reload it

For the previous question, I have already sent an answer, but maybe I forgot to post it. Now, I am using an interrupt in my STM32CubeMX, but I am confused because if the total number of arrays I input is 150, while the buffer is 200, the remaining 50 will become 0, resulting in a signal like that. The signal is similar but not the same, which is why I asked. I want the signal to repeat, but I am stuck and unable to move forward with this program @Gerhardh

@Ilya Now I want to make the signal repeat continuously. Do you have any suggestions? I am really stuck

@MeriaRajagukguk restart the same DMA transaction as soon as the current one is finished. DMA has a transfer complete interrupt. Sounds like a reasonable place to do that.

@Ilya Can you provide an example related to my program above? I’m really a beginner, so I find it a bit hard to imagine. I’m already using DMA, but I have to adjust the length according to the size of the array. However, that's not what I need. I want to eliminate the straight line after the valley and have the wave repeat continuously.

What straight line after the valley? If you want it like on the first picture, then you don't need to eliminate everything. You just need to do HAL_DAC_Start_DMA again in the DMA interrupt handler, it will reproduce the same waveform from the start: peak, straight piece, valley.

Activate DMA interrupts, activate DMA transfer complete interrupt; in the DMA IRQ handler you verify that it's transfer complete DMA flag that is set, and you do HAL_DAC_Start_DMA once again. This way the wave pattern will repeat forever. That's all you need. You just want your correct waveform pattern to repeat.

@Ilya It seems like you misunderstood. I want it to be like the second image, continuing with peaks, straight lines, valleys, peaks, straight lines, valleys, and so on.

Yes, I understood you correctly from the first time, I think. This is what I trying to help you achieve all this time. Ah, you mean you want some dead time after the valley? Then add some zeroes after the valley. And then repeat the pattern. What you have right now is a single period of Peak-Zero-Valley, you want Peak-Zero-Valley-Zero, repeat indefinitely.

Yes, that's exactly what I want, but when I use HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)value, index, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R); the value of index is not evaluated. I'm confused, is there something wrong with my code?  @Ilya

@MeriaRajagukguk where  do you put that line? In the DMA interrupt handler? Do you have access to the same index variable there?
